# AngularJS Date filter separately for time and date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have date time in this pattern in a object "order.date" in AngularJS

```
2017-04-27 08:34:51
```

I'm applying date filter here as `{{ order.date | date }}`

but its not working. I want to display date and time separately. Any help will be appreciated, Angular version is 1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

The Angular [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) needs a format:

```
{{order.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

#### [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/2m7qkjsd/)

Comment: Hi, I tried also applying format, it works with timestamp but not with a format like this 2017-04-27 08:34:51